# Function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

I try to call a function which passed as function pointer with no argument, but I can't make it work.

```
void *disconnectFunc;

void D::setDisconnectFunc(void (*func)){
    disconnectFunc = func;
}

void D::disconnected(){
    *disconnectFunc;
    connected = false;
}
```

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ can help.

Comment: @JRL cdecl doesn't help with that in particular (I tried cdecl before googling this question).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The correct way to do this is:

```
typedef void (*callback_function)(void); // type for conciseness

callback_function disconnectFunc; // variable to store function pointer type

void D::setDisconnectFunc(callback_function pFunc)
{
    disconnectFunc = pFunc; // store
}

void D::disconnected()
{
    disconnectFunc(); // call
    connected = false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using my preferred syntax of de-referencing a function pointer (prefer disconnectFunc() to (*disconnectFunc)(), even though they're both fine)

Comment: Is this portable way or it's not recommended to use for portability?

Comment: @JavaRunner: It's perfectly portable.

Comment: Fine. Thanks! Do you happen to know what I need to fix in that code if I need to pass function to setDisconnectFunc() with some parameters?

Comment: @JavaRunner: You should ask a new question if you need help extending it, the comment section is too constrained. There are many ways to do it, whatever your requirements are.

Comment: Putting this into a simple form with more understandable manner 1. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/ 2. http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html (also about how to return a function pointer)

Answer (score 13):

Replace `void *disconnectFunc;` with `void (*disconnectFunc)();` to declare function pointer type variable. Or even better use a `typedef`:

```
typedef void (*func_t)(); // pointer to function with no args and void return
...
func_t fptr; // variable of pointer to function
...
void D::setDisconnectFunc( func_t func )
{
    fptr = func;
}

void D::disconnected()
{
    fptr();
    connected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to declare disconnectFunc as a function pointer, not a void pointer.  You also need to call it as a function (with parentheses), and no "*" is needed.

Comment: Thank you.
Final code:


void (*disconnectFunc)();


void D::setDisconnectFunc(void (*func)()){
    disconnectFunc = func;
}


void D::disconnected(){
    (*disconnectFunc)();
    connected = false;
}