# How to pass into the function pointer to function?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a function which takes a pointer to another function? How does the prototype of such a function look like?

Comment: The function pointer tutorials: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Comment: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html or similar might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ function pointer as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582161/c-function-pointer-as-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef int (*func)(float, char);

int something_that_takes_a_func(func f) { return f(3.14, 3); }

int foo(float a, char b) { return a - b; }

std::cout << something_that_takes_a_func(&foo) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void f(int(*Func)())
{
    int a = Func();
}
```

and for a member function:

```
void f(int(cLass::*Func)())
{
    cLass *c = new cLass;
    int a = (c->*Func)();
}
```