# What does the (*) syntax in C++ mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

What does the following syntax mean?

```
set<element*, bool (*) (element *, element *)> * getNumbers();
```

I'm not familiar with the `(*)` part.  Any explanation would be great.  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ function pointer as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582161/c-function-pointer-as-parameter)

Comment: This would be a good place to use a typedef to make the code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 10):

Here it means that the second template parameter is a function pointer:

```
bool (*) (element *, element *)
```

is "pointer to a function that takes two `element*`s and returns `bool`".

You may also see `(*)` in connection with pointers to arrays;

```
int (*) [32]
```

is the type "pointer to an array of 32 `int`s".

Answer (score 2):

It is a function pointer, more precisely `bool (*) (element *, element *)` is the type of a function pointer. In this case its a function that takes two `element` pointers and returns a `bool`.

Its makes more sense when you see it used as function parameter, then it will have a name after the first `*`. For example `bool (*fun) (element *, element *)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function pointer. You can read about it further here, for example:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

`bool (*) (element *, element *)` names the type of a pointer to function, where the function takes two `element*` pointers as parameters and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Second template argument is function pointer, designed to compare 2 `element*`. If you put such function pointer in constructor of std::set - you will be able to create set of elements with custom compare function (or without overloaded operator<).