# Passing generic function for numerical integration with trapezoidal rule

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, generic-programming

I have a method for calculating the integral of a function using the trapezoidal rule. It works fine:

```
double trap_method(double a, double b, double n){

    int i = 1; double area = 0; double h = (b-a)/(n-1);
    double x = a+h;
    while(i <= n-2){

        area = area + exp(x)*h;
        x = x+h;
        i++;
    }
    area = area + (exp(a) + exp(b)) * h/2;

    return area;
}
```

However, as you can see, it only works for e<sup>*x*</sup> or whatever you hardcode into it.

I was wondering how I could add a parameter to `trap_method` such that I can just change the expression I want to integrate to whatever I want each time. Something like:

```
double trap_method(double a, double b, double n, function f){

    int i = 1; double area = 0; double h = (b-a)/(n-1);
    double x = a+h;
    while(i <= n-2){

        area = area + f(x)*h;
        x = x+h;
        i++;
    }
    area = area + (f(a) + f(b)) * h/2;

    return area;
}
```

Comment: See [Pointers to functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) What you have written doesn't provide the required syntax unless you have `function` typedeffed somewhere. (but yes, you can do what you are attempting to do) See also [Function pointer as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582161/function-pointer-as-parameter)

Comment: Look at [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which can happily take a function pointer or a lambda.

Comment: And if you are really lazy change `function` to `auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template<typename func_type>
double trap_method(double a, double b, double n, func_type f){

    int i = 1; double area = 0; double h = (b-a)/(n-1);
    double x = a+h;
    while(i <= n-2){

        area = area + f(x)*h;
        x = x+h;
        i++;
    }
    area = area + (f(a) + f(b)) * h/2;

    return area;
}
```

and then later....

```cpp
double result = trap_method(a, b, n, std::exp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If in ' trap_method ' I put a function ' f  ' that I have previously declared, does that work too? Edit: it does

Comment: Yup. because it's a template, func_type can be anything.

Comment: Have you tried to compile this code? `std::exp` names the overload [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp) of functions, `func_type` cannot be deduced from that set. This would work if you had only one non-template `std::exp` function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function pointer or template to pass lambda function.

```
double f(double x){
    return x*x;
}

double trap_method(double a, double b, int n, double (*func)(double)){

    int i = 1; double area = 0; double h = (b-a)/(n-1);
    double x = a+h;
    while(i <= n-2){

        area = area + func(x)*h;
        x = x+h;
        i++;
    }
    area = area + (func(a) + func(b)) * h/2;

    return area;
}

template<typename FUNC>
double trap_method(double a, double b, int n, FUNC func){

    int i = 1; double area = 0; double h = (b-a)/(n-1);
    double x = a+h;
    while(i <= n-2){

        area = area + func(x)*h;
        x = x+h;
        i++;
    }
    area = area + (func(a) + func(b)) * h/2;

    return area;
}
```

in main

```
cout << trap_method(0, 1, 100, f) << endl;
cout << trap_method(0, 1, 100, [](double x){return x*x;}) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm assuming the first half is the pointer method of doing it? In that case, does 'double (*fp) (double)' make it "point" to the function 'f' you made before hand? And if that function was instead name 'q' it would be 'double (*qp) (double)' ?

Comment: @AlejandroMatos no the parameter name does not have to be same. Modified answer.

Comment: @AlejandroMatos and your method is correct. I didn't see the last sum.