# Qt, pass parameter to a function

Tags: c++, qt

How can I pass a parameter to a function `getFunction` through a slot?

```
funcMenu->addAction("&1", garphArea, SLOT(getFunction(2)));
```

Comment: The slot receives a signal. You just have to emit the signal, passing the argument in it.

Answer (score 3):

With modern C++ and Qt5, the most simple way is to not connect directly to the slot, but [connect it to a lamda](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-5), which does what you want:

```
funcMenu->addAction("&1", graphArea, [graphArea](){
    graphArea->getFunction(2);
});
```

Above code assumes `graphArea` is a pointer, and captures it by value. You should study C++ lambdas to understand this more fully, or if you want more than just what is above. There are a lot of nuances and small dirty details in using lambdas (such as, when to capture by value, when by reference), and it's easy to use them wrong.

---

A historical note: In Qt4, the proper way to do this would have been to use [`QSignalMapper`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html), but it's in my opinion rather un-intuitive, and has more overhead than using a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-5) it is a `Functor`. The action's `triggered()` signal is connected to the functor. The functor can be a pointer to a member function of the *context* object.

So, in your case, the third argument should be a pointer to a member function of the context object `garphArea`

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582161/function-pointer-as-parameter) to understand how to pass function pointers around as arguments.

Moreover, the number of arguments in `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` must be matching. Here `triggered()` signal has no arguments so i am not sure you can directly connect to a member function accepting arguments. Maybe, connect to a member function with no arguments and call your desired function inside it.

**EDIT 1:**

I see that you are using [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-2) convenient function to call your slot. It states that the action's `triggered()` signal is connected to the *receiver's* member slot. But still to make it work, try calling without `SLOT` like:

```
funcMenu->addAction("&1", garphArea, getFunction());
```

or

```
funcMenu->addAction("&1", garphArea, getFunction);
```

I haven't tested this line of code but it should give you some idea. My comments above regarding arguments still holds true though.