# How to call a function from a std::variant of different return type function pointers?

Tags: c++, function, variant

How can you call a function from a `std::variant` of different return type function pointers?

For example, if I dont use `std::variant` (assuming the function return type is `void`):

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;;
}

void run_func(void (*func)())
{
    func();
}

int main()
{
    run_func(print);
}
```

Output:

`Hello World!` (as expected)

How can this be done while using a `std::variant` of return types, so that i can call functions of different return types.

For example:

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}

void run_func(std::variant<void (*)(), int (*)(), unsigned int (*)()> func)
{
    func(); // will return whatever type it is (void in this case)
}

int main()
{
    run_func(print);
}
```

The code above is non-functional but gives an idea of what im trying to explain.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve a non-function pointer object from a `std::variant`? If yes, where is the problem in adapting it for the function pointer version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function pointer as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582161/function-pointer-as-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must [*visit*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) your variant:

```
void run_func(std::variant<void (*)(), int (*)(), unsigned int (*)()> variant)
{
    std::visit([](auto fptr){fptr();}, variant);
}
```

### [Live C++17 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nW7xqnnbz)

---

If you actually want to get the `int` or `unsigned int` back out, we can return another variant as a result of calling `run_func`. I'll be using C++20 because it's more straightforward thanks to template parameter support for lambdas:

```
auto run_func(std::variant<void (*)(), int (*)(), unsigned int (*)()> variant)
 -> std::variant<std::monostate, int, unsigned int>
{
    using ret_t = std::variant<std::monostate, int, unsigned int>;
    return std::visit([]<class Ret>(Ret (*fptr)()) -> ret_t
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, Ret>)
        {
            fptr();
            return std::monostate{};
        }
        else
        {
            return fptr();
        }
    }, variant);
}
```

And we can call it like so:

```
int get_answer(){return 42;}

// ...

std::visit([](auto i){
        if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<decltype(i), std::monostate>)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }, run_func(&get_answer));
```

### [C++ 20 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9nnWEev9W)

With some more work, we could probably generalize `run_func` to accept any number of different function pointer types, and return an appropriate `variant`

---

## EDIT

For fun, I've generalized the code to accept any number of function types, with the restriction that none take any args (we *could* go that far if we really wanted to, though).

It requires we write a number of utility functions to operate on types:

- unique-ify a typelist (so our returned variant only contains the types it needs)
- remove `void` from a list of types (so that we don't try to return a variant with a `void` type)

Without further ado, here is that boilerplate:

```
template<class...>
struct typelist{};

template<class... T, class... U>
auto concat(typelist<T...>, typelist<U...>) -> typelist<T..., U...>;

// reduce the typelist to the set of unique types
auto unique(typelist<>) -> typelist<>;

template<class Head, class... Tail>
auto unique(typelist<Head, Tail...>)
 -> std::conditional_t<
        std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Head, Tail>...>, // predicate
        decltype(unique(std::declval<typelist<Tail...>>())), // true scenario: remove Head from typelist
        // false scenario, keep head, recurse on Tail and then concat to Head
        decltype(concat(std::declval<typelist<Head>>(),
             unique(std::declval<typelist<Tail...>>())))
        >; // conditional

template<class... T>
using unique_typelist = decltype(unique(std::declval<typelist<T...>>())); 

// remove the "type" void from the typelist
auto remove_void(typelist<>) -> typelist<>;

template<class Head, class... Tail>
auto remove_void(typelist<Head, Tail...>)
-> std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same_v<Head, void>, // predicate
    // true scenario: remove Head from typelist and recurse on Tail
    decltype(remove_void(std::declval<typelist<Tail...>>())),
    // false scenario: keep Head, recurse on Tail, then concat
    decltype(concat(std::declval<typelist<Head>>(), remove_void(std::declval<typelist<Tail...>>())))
    >;

template<class... T>
using typelist_without_void = decltype(remove_void(std::declval<typelist<T...>>())); 

template<class... T>
using unique_typelist_without_void = decltype(remove_void(unique(std::declval<typelist<T...>>()))); 

// make a variant from whatever is in the typelist
template<class... T>
auto make_variant(typelist<T...>) -> std::variant<T...>;

// make a variant from a typelist, but make the typlist unique and remove void from it first
template<class... T>
auto variant_from_typelist(typelist<T...>) -> decltype(make_variant(std::declval<unique_typelist_without_void<std::monostate, T...>>()));

template<class... T>
using variant_from_types = decltype(variant_from_typelist(std::declval<typelist<T...>>()));
```

For convenience, we'll add a type alias for function pointers as well as write a call-through for `run_func` so we can accept either a variant or a function pointer:

```
template<class T>
using fn_type = T(*)();

template<class... Ret>
auto run_func_impl(const std::variant<fn_type<Ret>...>& variant)
 -> variant_from_types<Ret...>
{
    return std::visit([]<class R>(R (*fptr)()) -> variant_from_types<Ret...>
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, R>)
        {
            fptr();
            return std::monostate{};
        }
        else
        {
            return fptr();
        }
    }, variant);
}

template<class R>
auto run_func(fn_type<R> fn) 
{
    return run_func_impl(std::variant<decltype(fn)>(fn));
}

template<class... Ret>
auto run_func(const std::variant<fn_type<Ret>...>& variant)
{
    return run_func_impl(variant);
}
```

Our test functions that we'll get pointers to for testing:

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}

int get_answer(){return 42;}

unsigned int third_function(){return 1337U;}
```

And finally, our tests:

```
auto visitor = [](auto i){
 if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<decltype(i), std::monostate>)
     std::cout << i << std::endl;
};
std::visit(visitor, run_func(&print));
std::visit(visitor, run_func(&get_answer));

std::variant<void(*)(), int(*)(), unsigned int(*)()> v(&print);
std::visit(visitor, run_func(v));

std::variant<void(*)(), int(*)(), unsigned int(*)()> v2(&get_answer);
std::visit(visitor, run_func(v2));

std::variant<void(*)(), int(*)(), unsigned int(*)()> v3(&third_function);
std::visit(visitor, run_func(v3));
```

### [Generic code demo (C++20)](https://godbolt.org/z/jYez5hPYb)

Comment: `uto` before run_func should be `auto`.

Comment: @anom1 fixed. plus added some extras

Comment: Wow! This really helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

`std::variant<>` contains exactly one of the types listed, and the type stored is known (and can be changed) *runtime*. Therefore, you cannot make the return type dependent on it, unless that's also a variant (void intentionally skipped):

```
std::variant<int, unsigned> run_func(int (*)(), unsigned int (*)()> func)
{ { std::visit([&](auto f) -> std::variant<int, unsigned> { return f(); }, func); }
 }
```

However, if all you need is to be able to process different outputs from a function, it's sometimes beneficial to use continuation passing style. It means, instead of returning, you accept a lambda that processes the output:

```
template<typename Cont>
void run_func(int (*)(), unsigned int (*)()> func, Cont cont)
{ std::visit([&](auto f) { cont(f); }, func); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a placeholder parameter with `auto`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;;
}

void print_int(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

void run_func(auto f)
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    run_func(print);
    run_func(std::bind(print_int, 1));
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
1
```

EDIT: just realized you asked specifically about `std::variant`, sorry, my answer might not be relevant

Comment: It's also worth noting that that is a C++20 feature (for declaring an abbreviated function template)

Comment: Ah I did not know this. This version https://godbolt.org/z/j17oeh7YT is afaik c++11 compatible. I'm assuming it's equivalent ?